# How to create back end for an form created using html

Tags: html

This is the html code i have written to create a form for my page how can i add back end to this form , actually through this form i want to store the messages from users onto my database.

```
<div class="col-md-6 to-animate">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="phone" class="sr-only">Phone</label>
        <input id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
        <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Send Message" type="submit" onclick="Send Message">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try with [`php`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) , [`mysql`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) and [`sql`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/deFault.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use any of the other technology such as PHP, .Net, or java or so to save the data into data base.

You can find the php based solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181733/submitting-a-form-using-php-to-store-information-in-a-database)

This is one of the easiest methods to get a simple contact form or save the user data into the database.